# spring boot jar only runs in specific directory using java -jar target/webapp.jar

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I am using maven to build my spring boot application into a .Jar file. When I move the jar out of the target directory and try to run it VIA the command line I get errors regarding port already in use. When I run the following command in the complete directory of the project, it works... eureka!

Command / Directory that works:

```
mvn clean install package && java -jar target/webapp.jar
```

Or this command works as long in the complete directory:

```
java -jar target/webapp.jar
```

Even if i change into the directory after a clean install command and try to run the jar using it does not work! Example below:

```
java -jar webapp.jar
```

It has to be run from the target directory! Does anyone have any ideas why this is??

Many thanks again..

Comment: `I get errors regarding port already in use` Did you try to find out which program is using this port? Probably, it's a spring boot app that wasn't shut down properly?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the cause, I had the following entries in my application.properties file for HTTPS settings.. :

```
#server.ssl.key-store=keystore.p12
#server.ssl.key-store-password=tpSalesforc3
#server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
#server.ssl.keyAlias=tomcat
```

The issue was my application could not find the keystore, which I will now store somewhere on the file system!